# postgres match through two lists (list in list)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, dbplyr, sql-in

I'd like to know if there is a way to check if there is at least one string in list a which matches in list b.

```
> select 1 IN (1,2);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

In the case above I'm only checking 1 value against a list.

But if I try as below I got error.

```
=> select (1, 3) IN (1,2);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: record = integer
LINE 1: select (1, 3) IN (1,2);
                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.


=> select ANY((1, 3) IN (1,2));
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 1: select ANY((1, 3) IN (1,2));
```

How do I perform this query??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use arrays instead of lists, and the `overlaps` operator:

```
select array[1, 3] && array[1, 2];
```

Yields

```
true
```

If you are starting from comma-delimited strings, you can use `string_to_array()` first:

```
select string_to_array('1,3', ',') && string_to_array('1,2', ',')
```

Comment: thanks, and if one array must be splited before?
`string_split("1,2", ",")`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes: you can use `string_to_array()` to split to turn a delimited string to an array. See my edited answer.

Comment: this way? `select "1" IN string_to_array("1,2", ",");` I got an error

Comment: Sorry return to this question, but this is right?
`select string_to_array('AAF38820.1,AAF38821.1', ',') && ARRAY(select product_accession FROM ftable LIMIT 10);` because I've got error.